# Ruby: Computed Style for a webpage

Tags: css, ruby, hpricot

I'm using Hpricot to parse an html page, but need to get the computed styles for each element.  For example, if I have an h1 Hpricot element and the external CSS for the page has a background-image defined for h1's, how can I find out what the background-image is?

Answer (score 0):

may be [Selenium framework](http://seleniumhq.org/) can help you?